# Finding text inbetween multiple tags using re

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find all the characters within  tags in python. Following is my code:

```
import re

text=''' <parse>(ROOT
      (S
      (NP (NNP Stanford) (NNP University))
      (VP (VBZ is)
      (ADJP (JJ located)
      (PP (IN in)
      (NP (NNP California)))))
      (. .)))

      </parse>
    <dependencies type="basic-dependencies">
      <dep type="root">
        <governor idx="0">ROOT</governor>
        <dependent idx="4">located</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="nn">
        <governor idx="2">University</governor>
        <dependent idx="1">Stanford</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="nsubj">
        <governor idx="4">located</governor>
        <dependent idx="2">University</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="cop">
        <governor idx="4">located</governor>
        <dependent idx="3">is</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="prep">
        <governor idx="4">located</governor>
        <dependent idx="5">in</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="pobj">
        <governor idx="5">in</governor>
        <dependent idx="6">California</dependent>
      </dep>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencies type="collapsed-dependencies">
      <dep type="root">
        <governor idx="0">ROOT</governor>
        <dependent idx="4">located</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="nn">
        <governor idx="2">University</governor>
        <dependent idx="1">Stanford</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="nsubj">
        <governor idx="4">located</governor>
        <dependent idx="2">University</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="cop">
        <governor idx="4">located</governor>
        <dependent idx="3">is</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="prep_in">
        <governor idx="4">located</governor>
        <dependent idx="6">California</dependent>
      </dep>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencies type="collapsed-ccprocessed-dependencies">
      <dep type="root">
        <governor idx="0">ROOT</governor>
        <dependent idx="4">located</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="nn">
        <governor idx="2">University</governor>
        <dependent idx="1">Stanford</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="nsubj">
        <governor idx="4">located</governor>
        <dependent idx="2">University</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="cop">
        <governor idx="4">located</governor>
        <dependent idx="3">is</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="prep_in">
        <governor idx="4">located</governor>
        <dependent idx="6">California</dependent>
      </dep>
    </dependencies>
  </sentence>
  <sentence id="2">
    <tokens>
      <token id="1">
        <word>It</word>
        <lemma>it</lemma>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>46</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>48</CharacterOffsetEnd>
        <POS>PRP</POS>
        <NER>O</NER>
      </token>
      <token id="2">
        <word>is</word>
        <lemma>be</lemma>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>49</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>51</CharacterOffsetEnd>
        <POS>VBZ</POS>
        <NER>O</NER>
      </token>
      <token id="3">
        <word>a</word>
        <lemma>a</lemma>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>52</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>53</CharacterOffsetEnd>
        <POS>DT</POS>
        <NER>O</NER>
      </token>
      <token id="4">
        <word>great</word>
        <lemma>great</lemma>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>54</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>59</CharacterOffsetEnd>
        <POS>JJ</POS>
        <NER>O</NER>
      </token>
      <token id="5">
        <word>university</word>
        <lemma>university</lemma>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>60</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>70</CharacterOffsetEnd>
        <POS>NN</POS>
        <NER>O</NER>
      </token>
      <token id="6">
        <word>,</word>
        <lemma>,</lemma>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>70</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>71</CharacterOffsetEnd>
        <POS>,</POS>
        <NER>O</NER>
      </token>
      <token id="7">
        <word>founded</word>
        <lemma>found</lemma>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>72</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>79</CharacterOffsetEnd>
        <POS>VBN</POS>
        <NER>O</NER>
      </token>
      <token id="8">
        <word>in</word>
        <lemma>in</lemma>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>80</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>82</CharacterOffsetEnd>
        <POS>IN</POS>
        <NER>O</NER>
      </token>
      <token id="9">
        <word>1891</word>
        <lemma>1891</lemma>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>83</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>87</CharacterOffsetEnd>
        <POS>CD</POS>
        <NER>DATE</NER>
        <NormalizedNER>1891</NormalizedNER>
        <Timex tid="t1" type="DATE">1891</Timex>
      </token>
      <token id="10">
        <word>.</word>
        <lemma>.</lemma>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>87</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>88</CharacterOffsetEnd>
        <POS>.</POS>
        <NER>O</NER>
      </token>
    </tokens>
    <parse>(ROOT
      (S
      (NP (PRP It))
      (VP (VBZ is)
      (NP
      (NP (DT a) (JJ great) (NN university))
      (, ,)
      (VP (VBN founded)
      (PP (IN in)
      (NP (CD 1891))))))
      (. .)))

      </parse>
    <dependencies type="basic-dependencies">
      <dep type="root">
        <governor idx="0">ROOT</governor>
        <dependent idx="5">university</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="nsubj">
        <governor idx="5">university</governor>
        <dependent idx="1">It</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="cop">
        <governor idx="5">university</governor>
        <dependent idx="2">is</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="det">
        <governor idx="5">university</governor>
        <dependent idx="3">a</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="amod">
        <governor idx="5">university</governor>
        <dependent idx="4">great</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="vmod">
        <governor idx="5">university</governor>
        <dependent idx="7">founded</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="prep">
        <governor idx="7">founded</governor>
        <dependent idx="8">in</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="pobj">
        <governor idx="8">in</governor>
        <dependent idx="9">1891</dependent>
      </dep>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencies type="collapsed-dependencies">
      <dep type="root">
        <governor idx="0">ROOT</governo'''


p1=re.compile("<parse>(.*)</parse>",re.DOTALL)
parse=p1.findall(text)
print parse
```

Output for the above code is:

```
['(ROOT\n          (S\n          (NP (NNP Stanford) (NNP University))\n          (VP (VBZ is)\n          (ADJP (JJ located)\n          (PP (IN in)\n          (NP (NNP California)))))\n          (. .)))\n\n          </parse>\n        <dependencies type="basic-dependencies">\n          <dep type="root">\n            <governor idx="0">ROOT</governor>\n            <dependent idx="4">located</dependent>\n          </dep>\n          <dep type="nn">\n            <governor idx="2">University</governor>\n            <dependent idx="1">Stanford</dependent>\n          </dep>\n          <dep type="nsubj">\n            <governor idx="4">located</governor>\n            <dependent idx="2">University</dependent>\n          </dep>\n          <dep type="cop">\n            <governor idx="4">located</governor>\n            <dependent idx="3">is</dependent>\n          </dep>\n          <dep type="prep">\n            <governor idx="4">located</governor>\n            <dependent idx="5">in</dependent>\n          </dep>\n          <dep type="pobj">\n            <governor idx="5">in</governor>\n            <dependent idx="6">California</dependent>\n          </dep>\n        </dependencies>\n        <dependencies type="collapsed-dependencies">\n          <dep type="root">\n            <governor idx="0">ROOT</governor>\n            <dependent idx="4">located</dependent>\n          </dep>\n          <dep type="nn">\n            <governor idx="2">University</governor>\n            <dependent idx="1">Stanford</dependent>\n          </dep>\n          <dep type="nsubj">\n            <governor idx="4">located</governor>\n            <dependent idx="2">University</dependent>\n          </dep>\n          <dep type="cop">\n            <governor idx="4">located</governor>\n            <dependent idx="3">is</dependent>\n          </dep>\n          <dep type="prep_in">\n            <governor idx="4">located</governor>\n            <dependent idx="6">California</dependent>\n          </dep>\n        </dependencies>\n        <dependencies type="collapsed-ccprocessed-dependencies">\n          <dep type="root">\n            <governor idx="0">ROOT</governor>\n            <dependent idx="4">located</dependent>\n          </dep>\n          <dep type="nn">\n            <governor idx="2">University</governor>\n            <dependent idx="1">Stanford</dependent>\n          </dep>\n          <dep type="nsubj">\n            <governor idx="4">located</governor>\n            <dependent idx="2">University</dependent>\n          </dep>\n          <dep type="cop">\n            <governor idx="4">located</governor>\n            <dependent idx="3">is</dependent>\n          </dep>\n          <dep type="prep_in">\n            <governor idx="4">located</governor>\n            <dependent idx="6">California</dependent>\n          </dep>\n        </dependencies>\n      </sentence>\n      <sentence id="2">\n        <tokens>\n          <token id="1">\n            <word>It</word>\n            <lemma>it</lemma>\n            <CharacterOffsetBegin>46</CharacterOffsetBegin>\n            <CharacterOffsetEnd>48</CharacterOffsetEnd>\n            <POS>PRP</POS>\n            <NER>O</NER>\n          </token>\n          <token id="2">\n            <word>is</word>\n            <lemma>be</lemma>\n            <CharacterOffsetBegin>49</CharacterOffsetBegin>\n            <CharacterOffsetEnd>51</CharacterOffsetEnd>\n            <POS>VBZ</POS>\n            <NER>O</NER>\n          </token>\n          <token id="3">\n            <word>a</word>\n            <lemma>a</lemma>\n            <CharacterOffsetBegin>52</CharacterOffsetBegin>\n            <CharacterOffsetEnd>53</CharacterOffsetEnd>\n            <POS>DT</POS>\n            <NER>O</NER>\n          </token>\n          <token id="4">\n            <word>great</word>\n            <lemma>great</lemma>\n            <CharacterOffsetBegin>54</CharacterOffsetBegin>\n            <CharacterOffsetEnd>59</CharacterOffsetEnd>\n            <POS>JJ</POS>\n            <NER>O</NER>\n          </token>\n          <token id="5">\n            <word>university</word>\n            <lemma>university</lemma>\n            <CharacterOffsetBegin>60</CharacterOffsetBegin>\n            <CharacterOffsetEnd>70</CharacterOffsetEnd>\n            <POS>NN</POS>\n            <NER>O</NER>\n          </token>\n          <token id="6">\n            <word>,</word>\n            <lemma>,</lemma>\n            <CharacterOffsetBegin>70</CharacterOffsetBegin>\n            <CharacterOffsetEnd>71</CharacterOffsetEnd>\n            <POS>,</POS>\n            <NER>O</NER>\n          </token>\n          <token id="7">\n            <word>founded</word>\n            <lemma>found</lemma>\n            <CharacterOffsetBegin>72</CharacterOffsetBegin>\n            <CharacterOffsetEnd>79</CharacterOffsetEnd>\n            <POS>VBN</POS>\n            <NER>O</NER>\n          </token>\n          <token id="8">\n            <word>in</word>\n            <lemma>in</lemma>\n            <CharacterOffsetBegin>80</CharacterOffsetBegin>\n            <CharacterOffsetEnd>82</CharacterOffsetEnd>\n            <POS>IN</POS>\n            <NER>O</NER>\n          </token>\n          <token id="9">\n            <word>1891</word>\n            <lemma>1891</lemma>\n            <CharacterOffsetBegin>83</CharacterOffsetBegin>\n            <CharacterOffsetEnd>87</CharacterOffsetEnd>\n            <POS>CD</POS>\n            <NER>DATE</NER>\n            <NormalizedNER>1891</NormalizedNER>\n            <Timex tid="t1" type="DATE">1891</Timex>\n          </token>\n          <token id="10">\n            <word>.</word>\n            <lemma>.</lemma>\n            <CharacterOffsetBegin>87</CharacterOffsetBegin>\n            <CharacterOffsetEnd>88</CharacterOffsetEnd>\n            <POS>.</POS>\n            <NER>O</NER>\n          </token>\n        </tokens>\n        <parse>(ROOT\n          (S\n          (NP (PRP It))\n          (VP (VBZ is)\n          (NP\n          (NP (DT a) (JJ great) (NN university))\n          (, ,)\n          (VP (VBN founded)\n          (PP (IN in)\n          (NP (CD 1891))))))\n          (. .)))\n\n          ']
```

But I need only the characters within the parse tags, nothing else. Please solve this. Following should be the output:

```
'(ROOT\n          (S\n          (NP (NNP Stanford) (NNP University))\n          (VP (VBZ is)\n          (ADJP (JJ located)\n          (PP (IN in)\n          (NP (NNP California)))))\n          (. .)))\n\n        
(ROOT\n          (S\n          (NP (PRP It))\n          (VP (VBZ is)\n          (NP\n          (NP (DT a) (JJ great) (NN university))\n          (, ,)\n          (VP (VBN founded)\n          (PP (IN in)\n          (NP (CD 1891))))))\n          (. .)))\n\n
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `p1=re.compile("<parse>(.*?)</parse>",re.DOTALL)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use a regex, use this one:

```
(?s)<parse>(.*?)</parse>
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rF9qP9/1)

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?s)<parse>(.*?)</parse>')
parse = re.findall(p, text)
print parse
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `BeautifulSoup` parser.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
>>> for i in soup.select('parse'):
        print(i.text)


(ROOT
      (S
      (NP (NNP Stanford) (NNP University))
      (VP (VBZ is)
      (ADJP (JJ located)
      (PP (IN in)
      (NP (NNP California)))))
      (. .)))


(ROOT
      (S
      (NP (PRP It))
      (VP (VBZ is)
      (NP
      (NP (DT a) (JJ great) (NN university))
      (, ,)
      (VP (VBN founded)
      (PP (IN in)
      (NP (CD 1891))))))
      (. .)))
```

Comment: **+1** This is definitely the right way to go. Otherwise the parser will still read `<!-- we no longer want this: <parse>(DO (BAD THINGS))</parse> -->`

Comment: You really want `BeautifulSoup(text, "xml")` though

Comment: @Eric i tried, but it won't recognize the second parse tag.

Comment: That's because the xml is invalid and missing a top-level element